# Linking with -static-libstdc++ flag on MinGW 4.7.1

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, mingw32, allegro

I try to compile with Allegro 5 on MinGW 4.7.1 using Code::Blocks 12.11 on Windows 7 with these compiler flags (In **Project** > **Linker settings** > **Other linker settings**):

```
-static-libgcc  
-static-libstdc++
```

Result:

```
unrecognized command line option '-static-libstdc++'
```

How to solve it?

Comment: This is surely not off-topic IMHO. I think that code compilation issues/errors given by a C++ compiler is on-topic.

Answer (score 9):

What does `g++ --version` say?  I don't know the exact version
when it was introduced, but `-static-libstdc++` is a fairly
recent addition.  Before, you had to do something like `-static
-lstdc++ -dynamic`.  (If the compiler version is 4.7.1, this
should not be a problem, but I don't know how MinGW versions map
to the actual compiler version.)

Comment: Wow, it says 4.6.2. I was sure it is 4.7.1. since there is mingw32-gcc-4.7.1.exe in distributive.

Comment: There is also a directory gcc\mingw32\4.7.1 in the distributive. What a chaos.

Comment: @toprightgamedev IIRC (it's been a while since I've installed MingW---my current PC is Linux), there are several versions you can choose from on the download page.  But the surest statement, in this regard, is what `g++ --version` says, since it is compiled in.  But as another poster said: find where the libraries are located, and see if there is a `libstdc++.a` present.  If not, download one.  And make sure it is in the same directory; if g++ finds a `libstdc++.so` in an earlier directory, it won't look any further.

Comment: I've set explicit path to `libstdc++.a` and compile with the only "Other linker options": `-static-libgcc`. It says: `undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'` and `undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
`

Comment: This can also happen when using mingw  with `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` linker flags. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779224/exceptions-not-caught-when-linking-static-libs

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested but try to separate as `-static  -libstdc++`

Comment: "cannot find -libstdc++"

Comment: there is libstdc++.a in MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32

Comment: @toprightgamedev That's a good question.  If there's no static library present, g++ can't link with it.  (If there isn't, it's a bit silly, because I can't think of any case where you'd want to link the c++ standard library dynamicallyl)

Comment: Yes, MinGW 4.7.1 (that was installed with Code::Blocks 12.11) has only libstdc++.a (searched by `libstdc`)

Comment: I wanted to ask about it on Code::Blocks forums, but still waiting registration approval from admin... :]

Comment: Replace "-libstdc++" with "lstdc++" I would think...