# Lua DLL Library Dependencies

Tags: c++, windows, dll, lua

I created a lua module for windows, a DLL, which has a number of dependencies. These dependencies are required for the module DLL to function correctly, most of these dependencies are C++ runtime libraries (libstdc+-6.dll and libgcc_s_seh-1.dll among others). I am trying to load the module using the `package.loadlib` call:

```
init = assert(package.loadlib("C:\\Path\\To\\My\\Module.DLL", "luaopen_MyModule"))
init()
```

The dependencies and module DLL are located in another folder than the main executable's DLL. Because of this, it seems like `package.loadlib` cannot find the dependencies of the module. It works fine when the path to these dependencies is added to the PATH variable, but I am not allowed to modify PATH on the machines where the lua module will be used, neither can I link to the dependencies statically.

Is there any way to specify a search path for the dependencies from lua? The lua will only be used on Windows systems, so the solution may be platform dependent.

Comment: You could require that those dll's are bundled along and moved with your dll? You could also try to statically link `libstdc++-6.dll` into your dll, so that an external dll is not needed. Mingw has an option for this, don't remember how it's called...

Comment: The other dll's are in the same folder as my dll, but in another folder than the main executable program. The option you are looking for is -static, but I am not allowed to use static linking to the standard libraries.

Comment: There is an extra one now: `-static-libstdc++` see more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225083/linking-with-static-libstdc-flag-on-mingw-4-7-1 I don't know if there is an equivalent thing for the `seh` dll.

Comment: An equivalent exists for the other dll, the option was called -static-libgcc, but as said in the question, static linking is forbidden. So that is not really an option.

Comment: You could always call the Windows API function [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206.aspx). The change is _only_ for your process, that is, the variable you change doesn't propagate back to the system settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no way to statically include those dependencies or modify the PATH to affect the DLL search, you can try another option: just load those dependencies directly using the same `package.loadlib` call before you load your `Module.DLL`. I used this in a situation when I wanted to make sure that the DLL my libraries depend on was loaded from the correct location:

```
package.loadlib([[C:\Path\To\Whatever\libstdc++-6.dll]], "")
init = assert(package.loadlib("C:\\Path\\To\\My\\Module.DLL", "luaopen_MyModule"))
init()
```