# Exceptions not caught when linking static libs

Tags: c++, gcc, exception

I started implementing a try/catch in my program, but when I was testing it, the exceptions were never caught and the program just crashes. Even the simplest use case of a try/catch would fail, i.e

```
try
{
    throw 123;
}
catch (...)
{
    cerr << "This line doesn't get hit." << endl;
}
```

After lots of digging around researching how exceptions work and debugging, I finally found that the issue was because I was linking with specifically `-static-libstdc++` which was causing the break. The exceptions work fine when this flag isn't set. After further research I found [this bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14271), but I can't really figure out what the status is on it. It appears that the issue is still at large, but according to [this earlier bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53730) it seems that there might be a work around according to the comments. Unfortunately I don't understand exactly what all the comments mean and what they did to get it to work if at all outside of building GCC manually (which I'd like to avoid if I can).

Is there a way to resolve this bug while still linking the static standard lib and how would I go about it?

Comment: Why were you linking with `-static-libstdc++`?

Comment: I'm building my program for Windows and it's just easier to statically link the lib with the executable than always pair a DLL with it.